# Coutable additivity argument in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have two stochastic processes $X$ and $Y$ such that for each $t\ge0$, $P(X(t)=Y(t))=1$

I read often something like: by "countable additivity", we can find a countable set $T \subset \mathbb R^+$ such that $P(X(t)=Y(t), \forall t \in T)=1$

How do we construct such a $T$ ? Where does the countable additivity of $P$ play a role ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result holds for any countable set $T$.  For $t_i \in T$, let $A_i$ be the event $X(t_i)=Y(t_i)$.  This event occurs almost surely.  By countable additivity, the intersection of a countable number of almost sure events is almost sure.  Your event, $X(t)=Y(t), \forall t \in T$ is the intersection of the $A_i$, so has probability one.